# How do TLD DNS nameservers acquire records for authoritative nameservers

Tags: dns, domain, isp

I'm going to make a few assumptions based on my current knowledge, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Lets say you want to go to www.example.com but your browser, host and ISP nameserver do not have the DNS entry cached. The ISP nameserver does not know the authoritative nameserver for example.com either.

At this point the ISP-nameserver would query the .com TLD nameserver. This server would return the authoritative nameserver for example.com (ie. ns1.example.com) which would then be used to query the A record for www.example.com.

My question is: How does the TLD nameserver for the .com domain 'know' the authoritative namesservers for example.com. How does it acquire this information?

When a new domain is registered the NS records are created and must be propagated to the TLD nameserver somehow. How does this work?

Comment: You as a company or a person interested in owning a DNS name would reach out to a DNS provider and work with them on that part. Your ISP can have absolutely nothing to do with this for example if you buy DNS certs from GoDaddy and use Comcast for ISP. I think you're making an incorrect assumption so look over GoDaddy.com and how that works (that's only one provider) but they can manager the DNS records for a domain for you or allow you to do so. You'd work with your ISP to setup "reverse" DNS records though and tell them to point one of their IP's to a DNS you setup that you own. (cont)

Comment: So since Comcast may give you a public IP block, you may want to have a valid reverse DNS lookup to point back to your servers on the other side of your IPS router and firewalls so you tell Comcast to setup in their DNS that they control to say ip x.x.x.x points to your DNS record of <domain>.com

Answer (score 6):

> How does the TLD nameserver for the .com domain 'know' the authoritative namesservers for example.com. How does it acquire this information?

You and your domain registrar tell it.

When you enter the authoritative nameservers e.g. *ns1.example.com* and *ns2.example.com*, this information is updated (via the registrar) with Verisign Inc., the company that currently runs the *.com* servers.

It's also probably worth noting that registries can run registrar services themselves (so, depending on who runs the TLD and who you choose to register with, there may not actually be a difference between them.)

> When a new domain is registered the NS records are created and must be propagated to the TLD nameserver somehow. How does this work?

I honestly have never found good information on the communication lines between 3rd-party registrars and registries, but I am pretty sure it is fairly direct (even if delayed).

The delay experienced between registering a domain and/or updating nameservers often has much more to do with record updates on other DNS servers.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is:

1. The registrar requests the domain creation at the registry, via EPP (Extensible Provisioning Protocol) or some registry API. Note the request can include a list of name servers.
2. After validation, the registry stores the new domain information into a database.
3. The registry uses that information to update their DNS name servers, using DDNS (Dynamic DNS).

Thank you for asking. I had the exact same question and wrote [a blog post about it](https://foudil.fr/blog/posts/dns-tld-domain-delegation/). See also
https://www.afnic.fr/en/observatory-and-resources/expert-papers/what-happens-when-you-register-a-domain-name/.